# Deploying Docker-compose in to production

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I didn't understand anything what is the best way to deploy my docker service to production?

My compose file:

```
services:
  app:
    container_name: "barbut"
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
    volumes:
    - ./app/:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: bash -c "/usr/wait-for-it.sh --timeout=0 mongo:27017 && pm2-dev start ecosystem.config.js"

  redis:
    container_name: barbutRedis
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
  mongo:
    container_name: barbutMongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
    - mongoData:/data/db
  nginx:
    container_name: barbutNginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
    - "80:80"

volumes:
  mongoData:
```

What is the next step? I guess I need to build this image then upload it to Docker hub then pull this image to my server and build again. But I didn't understand how can I do this.

Comment: There are a bunch of Compose options that will cause difficulties in a production environment (especially `volumes:`, the `command:` override too) or that are just unnecessary (`container_name:`, `hostname:`, `links:`).  One good place to start would be removing all of these options and making the stack work without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compose file you have isn't an image itself; its a means to manage a collection of images. This mean you wouldn't upload the docker-compose file itself to dockerhub, but rather the images for each service. 'Deploying' a docker-compose file is (generally) a matter of copying the docker-compose file to your server and running `docker-compose up -d` (or making a service that automates this, perhaps with systemd). Any image in the compose file will be pulled automatically.

For your specific compose file, you are defining the images locally for the `nginx` service and the `app` service, in which case you have two options:

1. Copy `./nginx` and/or `./app` to your server and run the compose file as-is. This will build the image locally when you call `docker-compose` and skip uploading it to dockerhub
2. run `docker build ./app -t yourtag` (and same for `./nginx` if desired) and push to dockerhub with `docker push yourimage:yourtag`. In that case you would need to edit the compose file to pull the images and tags you defined when building them.